# Weird indexing with 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, indexing, 2d

```
def matrix_multiply(arr0, arr1):
    finalrow = len(arr0)
    finalcolumn = len(arr1[0])
    final = [[None]*finalcolumn] *finalrow
    print (final)
    for j in range(len(arr0)):
        for k in range(len(arr0)):
            summ = 0
            for i in range(len(arr0[0])):
                print ("i:", i, "j:",j,"k:",k)
                summ += arr0[j][i] * arr1[i][k]
            print (summ)
            print ("j:", j ,"k:",k)
            final[j][k] = summ
            print (final)
    return final
```

So I am creating a basic function for a class to multiply 2 matrices and it seems that my above algorithm should work but I'm having weird indexing problems.

```
arr2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
arr3 = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [5, 8]]
matrix_multiply(arr2, arr3)

[[None, None], [None, None]]
i: 0 j: 0 k: 0
i: 1 j: 0 k: 0
i: 2 j: 0 k: 0
20
j: 0 k: 0
[[20, None], [20, None]]
i: 0 j: 0 k: 1
i: 1 j: 0 k: 1
i: 2 j: 0 k: 1
34
j: 0 k: 1
[[20, 34], [20, 34]]
i: 0 j: 1 k: 0
i: 1 j: 1 k: 0
i: 2 j: 1 k: 0
44
j: 1 k: 0
[[44, 34], [44, 34]]
i: 0 j: 1 k: 1
i: 1 j: 1 k: 1
i: 2 j: 1 k: 1
76
j: 1 k: 1
[[44, 76], [44, 76]]
[[44, 76], [44, 76]]
```

If i use the 3 example lines of code to call my function I get this output. I don't understand why every time I do final[i][j] it puts the number in 2 locations in the array. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One first error before the big one is your ranges, think what you meant to do was :

```
for i in range( len( final ) ):
    for j in range( len( final[0] ):
```

It is often expected to index rows with i and columns with j.

For the double writing error this is due to your

```
final = [ [ None ] *  finalRow ] * finalColumn
```

and this does not copy your [ None, None,.. , None ] list meaning :
they all have the same reference in memory ie when you modify the first one you modify the others as we are talking about the same lists.

Comment: if i did that, how would it do the matrix multiplication correctly? because  then ill be using a 2 X 2 array to try and get all the elements for a 2 X 3 and 3 X 2

Comment: You will not be able to do matrix multiplication using only arr0 size. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition